# writing a method body as Expression<>

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I want to convert a logic inside a method as a Expression, so that i could store that and when required could compile it for execution.

The method has flow like

1) takes a parameter

2) does a 'FirstOrDefault' on a collection property on passed in parameter

3) Calls some method on a repository class

4) some if conditions

5) creation/instantiation of some field

etc etc. In all a complex method which does lots of things.

Question : Is there any article/resource which could show me this with an example.

Thanks

Comment: Why does that needs to be a `Expression`? Can't you have it as a method?

Comment: @Sriram,it is already a method but there was some pointer in the team to have it as a expression so that it act as a data structure rather than a code.

Comment: @PrerakK You should really ask why that is important. It's usually preferred to have code as code, rather than data - you only really want code-as-data if you intend to be modifying it at runtime, or if you need to do something that you can't do otherwise - and quite often, it's better to think of a different approach anyway (repository dictionaries? Dependency injection?), unless you're really, really concerned about performance. Which is it for you? :)

Comment: @Luaan, given that it might not be necessary but still i am really interested if that is doable? at least i'll know if that is supported by c# and if supported how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with MSDN? You can find examples here (at the bottom of the page):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Something like this:

```
static Expression<Action<IEnumerable<int>>> BuildExpression()
{
    ParameterExpression param1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<int>), "param1");
    Expression<Func<IEnumerable<int>, int>> firstOrDefault = collection => collection.FirstOrDefault();
    Expression body = Expression.Condition(
        Expression.LessThan(
            Expression.Invoke(firstOrDefault, param1),
            Expression.Constant(10)),
        Expression.Call(
            typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new [] { typeof(string) }),
            Expression.Constant("Less")),
        Expression.Call(
            typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new [] { typeof(string) }),
            Expression.Constant("Greater or equal"))
        );
    return Expression.Lambda<Action<IEnumerable<int>>>(body, new[] { param1 });
}
```

Comment: nothing wrong, but some how i am not able to follow them. For example i want to write expression tree for var result = someCollection.FirstOrDefault(predicate); if(result.value>10){do something else};